# What does 'sandboxed' webview actually mean?

Tags: chrome-for-android, webview

I keep hearing the argument for Tinfoil for Facebook(vs mobile site) that it is sandboxed. What does it actually mean? what can websites access on normal web browsers that they can't on isolated WebViews?